# AJAX iterating through database values in for-in loop but not in click event

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm making an AJAX call to a database which populates a div element and when a user clicks on a button, it populates based on what they clicked.  When I do a console log within the for-in loop, the script iterates correctly through each table and prints each desired value to the console.  However, when I place the console into a click event outside the loop, I only get the values from the last table.

**jQuery**

```
$.post("../php/populate_script.php", function(data){
    jsonData = window.JSON.parse(data);
    var row = data;
    var scenario_id;
    var date_created;
    var initials;
    var aircraft;
    var city1;
    for(var i in jsonData){
        row = jsonData[i];
        scenario_id = row["id"];
        date_created = row["created"];
        initials = row["initials"];
        aircraft = row["aircraft"];
        city1 = row["city_pair1"];
        console.log(city1);
    }
    $(".view").each(function(){
        $(this).on("click", function(){
            console.log(city1);
        })
    })
})
```

Log I see when the console.log is within the for-in loop

[image]

Log I see when the console.log is within the click event

[image]

As you can see, it's only returning the last value in the click event.  Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do this would be to place the variables that hold your values into an object `ScenarionInfo[i]{}`and in the click event, use one of the values as your iterator constant, for instance the id field.  So in your click event, place something like this

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

and then simply append the values where you want them.

Answer (score 1):

*city1* is a variable defined in the post callback scope. The function

```
function(){
    console.log(city1);
}
```

Is executed only when one of the elements with .view class is actually clicked. At that time the *city1* variable has the last value assigned to it, which is "2" in your case.

You can save the variables on the element itself using the [data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) method, something like this:

```
for(var i in jsonData){
    row = jsonData[i];
    scenario_id = row["id"];
    date_created = row["created"];
    initials = row["initials"];
    aircraft = row["aircraft"];
    city1 = row["city_pair1"];

    ... create you button in the dom ...

    button.addClass('view');
    button.data('row', row);

    console.log(city1);
}
```

Then you can retrieve the city in the click callback as follows:

```
$(".view").on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).data('row'));
});
```

Note that you can avoid the use of each, and directly bind the click event on each element with class .view.

Comment: Would this work if I had multiple values to retrieve?

Comment: I edited my answer, you can save all the row data in the same way. Every JS object or array can be stored using the data() method.

Comment: @RobbyT15 You can store the entire `row` object in the `button`'s data, instead of just the city: `button.data('row', row);`

Comment: I'm actually getting an undefined value using this method.

Comment: Can you post all your code? I should know how you create your buttons to help you.

Comment: @baxeico I actually got it working.  I'm gonna accept your answer since you provided the most help.